# How to reduce the size of Sencha Touch Application?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am building a Sencha Touch application. Even the most basic application is of size 27 MB. Now I want to commit the code online. The touch folder inside the application is of 20 MB which is way too much.
So how can I compress my application and reduce the size of my application?

Answer (score 0):

use sencha cmd to minify to one js file.

from the application's root in the terminal or command prompt, run "sencha app build production" or "sencha app build testing" dependent on if you want the source code minified also.

Make sure you have sencha cmd installed first.

Also make sure each of your classes is requiring only the source components you need. What you're doing right now is deploying every single line of sencha touch, whereas in reality, if you're not using the carousel component, for instance, you don't need this in your deployed app.

Requiring in the classes you need only, and then building the app file in this way, will give you a nice compact single js file that is many many times smaller.

Answer (score 0):

At first, what do you want is not clear. Why you want to compress the application?
If you want to run it on device, you can minify it using sencha cmd. From within your application folder run this command

`sencha app build production`

and you can see your app size(build version) will reduce drastically. Further you can make apk and/or ipa with this build version only.